# OSX Python Jupyter notebook Brunel "No Java runtime present..."

Tags: java, python, macos

Executing brunel code inside Jupyter notebook on OSX causes "No Java runtime present..." and asks to install Java 6!!!

Here's the configuration:
OSX 10.12.5 with Java JDK 1.8 installed
Python 3.6.1
Jupyter 4.3.0
Brunel 2.3

Here's the code in Jupyter notebook ("data" has been set in a previous cell.):

```
import brunel
%brunel data('data') x('category') y('penalty')
```

I did the following:
JAVA_HOME has been set and "java -version" returns the correct version (1.8). 
OSX comes with Python 2, Python3 was installed by me. Jupyter notebook has been running fine until I try Brunel for visualization. I added a symlink python->python3.

When executing the above code, dialog box pops up to ask to install Java 6 while I already have Java 8 installed.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it is asking for a JRE, not a JDK. On the MacOS X, these are two separate things - the JRE is installed in a way that is hard to access through command line, but applications can easily find it, and you have a control panel for it. A JDK is for developers, and doesn't have a graphical control panel or automatic updates.